# Create duplicate flag based on ids and dates

Tags: r, data.table

Let's suppose I have this:

```
id <- rep(1:3, 5)
dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2017-05-01"), by=1, len=5), 3)
DT <- data.table(id, dates)
setkey(DT, dates)
```

It looks like this:

```
    id      dates
 1:  1 2017-05-01
 2:  3 2017-05-01
 3:  2 2017-05-01
 4:  2 2017-05-02
 5:  1 2017-05-02
 6:  3 2017-05-02
 7:  3 2017-05-03
 8:  2 2017-05-03
 9:  1 2017-05-03
10:  1 2017-05-04
11:  3 2017-05-04
12:  2 2017-05-04
13:  2 2017-05-05
14:  1 2017-05-05
15:  3 2017-05-05
```

I want to create a column "duplicate_flag" where the first appearance should be 0 and the followings should be 1.

This is my expected output:

```
     id   dates    duplicate_flag
 1:  1 2017-05-01     0
 2:  3 2017-05-01     0
 3:  2 2017-05-01     0
 4:  2 2017-05-02     1
 5:  1 2017-05-02     1
 ...
```

Comment: @bouncyball No.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way: group by `id`, then set flag according to whether each date equals the minimum date in the group.

`DT[, duplicate := dates != min(dates), by =id]`

Which gives:

```
   id      dates duplicate
 1:  1 2017-05-01     FALSE
 2:  3 2017-05-01     FALSE
 3:  2 2017-05-01     FALSE
 4:  2 2017-05-02      TRUE
 5:  1 2017-05-02      TRUE
 6:  3 2017-05-02      TRUE
 7:  3 2017-05-03      TRUE
 8:  2 2017-05-03      TRUE
 9:  1 2017-05-03      TRUE
10:  1 2017-05-04      TRUE
11:  3 2017-05-04      TRUE
12:  2 2017-05-04      TRUE
13:  2 2017-05-05      TRUE
14:  1 2017-05-05      TRUE
15:  3 2017-05-05      TRUE
```

You can wrap with `as.numeric()` if you want 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE

The above uses data.table, since that's what you use in the OP, but the same thing in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(duplicate = dates != min(dates))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table:

```
DT[, duplicate_flag:=ifelse(c(1:.N)==1,0,1), by=id]
```

and you get this :

```
DT
    id      dates duplicate_flag
 1:  1 2017-05-01              0
 2:  3 2017-05-01              0
 3:  2 2017-05-01              0
 4:  2 2017-05-02              1
 5:  1 2017-05-02              1
 6:  3 2017-05-02              1
 7:  3 2017-05-03              1
 8:  2 2017-05-03              1
 9:  1 2017-05-03              1
10:  1 2017-05-04              1
11:  3 2017-05-04              1
12:  2 2017-05-04              1
13:  2 2017-05-05              1
14:  1 2017-05-05              1
15:  3 2017-05-05              1
```

Comment: One note - this answer assumes each subset of data grouped by id is sorted by `dates` (which is true here because OP included the line `setkey(dates)`), but it wouldn't work absent correct pre-sorting